# Play[2.2] websocket USA Today api error com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value

Tags: java, rest, playframework, websocket

I am trying to make a call to the USA Today api using this call in Play:

```
public static Promise<Result> feedZilla() {
final Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url("http://api.usatoday.com/open/articles/topnews/home?count=10&days=0&page=0&encoding=json&api_key=(My Key).get().map(
        new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
            public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                                JsonNode json = response.asJson();
return ok(json);
            }
        }
);
return resultPromise;
}
```

But I keep getting this error message:

```
error com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value
```

I'm pretty sure the code and url are valid. The code worked before when I was using FeedZilla's api, and the url works in Postman. Not sure what is going on. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It looks like a syntax error in the response. You can print the response text to see what you are getting back from the server. (Unrelated: the url string  does not have a closing `"`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accidentally deleted the " when I removed my key before posting. The response Play is getting is <h1> Developer Inactive</h1>. Not sure what that is all about because the url works in Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Apparently play doesn't like hard coding the query parameters in the url like that. I had to set them using the .setQueryParameter(""paramKey", "paramValue");